# How to create a proxy for WCF service hosted in windows apps

Tags: c#, wcf

i am beginner for WCF. so i was reading a code online for small wcf chat.i got stuck to create wcf client for that wcf chat. the url from where i was reading http://islameldemery.blogspot.in/2008/05/wcf-serverclient-chat-sample.html

there is one part for interface and service is hosted in win form with the help of **ServiceHost** but i am not being able to understand how proxy was created at client end.

they use this event below

```
InnerDuplexChannel.Opened
InnerDuplexChannel.Closed
InnerDuplexChannel.Faulted
```

which i really do not understand. can anyone tell me how the client was created. please visit the url and please tell me how that person create a proxy at client side for that chat service.

i tried to create a proxy dynamically like self hosted as

```
var myBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
  DuplexChannelFactory<ISampleChatCallback> cf =
          new DuplexChannelFactory<ISampleChatCallback>(
              new CallbackImpl(),
              myBinding,
              new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://192.168.1.2:8080/DataService")); 
  IServerWithCallback srv = cf.CreateChannel();
```

but srv  has no event called Opened,Closed or faulted etc. i really need to understand how proxy was created at cleint end. please help me to create proxy as a result i can complete the code for client side. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

```
if (CheckServer()) //this seems to get metadata (MEX) from server
{
    proxy = null;
    InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(this);

    // Step into this method and see what code gets executed.
    // This code can be generated by Visual Studio or written manually
    proxy = new Client.SampleService.SampleChatClient(context);

    proxy.InnerDuplexChannel.Opened += new EventHandler(InnerDuplexChannel_Opened);
    ...
}
```

The `proxy` exposes some events that (I suppose) are just wrappers of the WCF duplex channel communication class (whatever it is). Those events get fired when a new connection is opened, closed or appears in a faulted state.

Comment: i copy that code but got error.proxy this word gives error at compile time. can u please tell me any portion of code is missing in that article for which proxy word is giving error. thanks

Comment: @Thomas the source code isn't available, so I guess he used VS to generate client code. Try [adding a reference](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how+to+add+reference+to+wcf+service) (to the WCF service) to your client project. This shall be in the context menu, right click on the client project and select **Add service reference...**. Make sure you give a new reference consistent name, I think it is *Client.SampleService.SampleChatClient*

Comment: i know how to add service reference but i do not understand what url i have to type for service reference.can u suggest. thanks

Comment: so tell when there is no .svc file in service end then how one can add service reference.if u go to the code then u can see there was no .svc file reference.

Comment: @Thomas can you separately start server? This is the URL you need to provide. In the example it is *net.tcp://localhost:4477/SampleWCFChat/* or *http://localhost:4478/SampleWCFChat/*

Comment: @Tomas, will it be helpful to look at a very simple duplex communication sample? I wrote [this](http://blog.devlex.net/post/2011/09/24/Sample-WCF-contract-callback.aspx) a while ago, there is full source code and some explanation. It's not a chat application, but a this can be converted into chat.

Comment: there is 3 projects i created.one class library where all interface there. one windows app which is for server end and one windows apps which is for client end. i tried to add this url as service ref but got error.any suggestion

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21188/discussion-between-oleksii-and-thomas)

Answer (score 1):

WCF clients for .NET are generated using  a command line tool called `svcutil.exe` that can generate the proxy, which is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751905.aspx. A quite common other way to generate them is to add a service reference to your project in Visual Studio, which ends up generating the same proxy as using `svcutil`. This process is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx

Svcutil will generate the necessary proxy classes for you and uses a `Channel` internally for the communication. It is for this channel that the states `Opened`, `Closed` and `Faulted` are defined.

Comment: the problem is there is no svc file. just few interface and one winform which extend those interface.so when i add going for add service reference option and click on discover button then nothing happen.i am new...so not being able to understand how to add the service reference.can u please go to the url from where i copy the code and just tell me how to create proxy for that kind service??

Comment: when people use svcutil tool to generate proxy then proxy related classes stored where...i never use it before. please help.

Comment: Visual Studio creates a subdirectory for all the files it generates. But you normally don't have to look at those.